# Can´t log on to subsite in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

We have 4 sites on our network.
mainsite.com, dev.mainsite.com, site2.com, and dev.site2.com.
But we can´t log on to site2.com and dev.site2.com?
We are not using any plugin since: [WordPress 4.5+, domain mapping is a native feature.](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

1) Navigate to the network dashboard using networkdomain/wp-admin/network

2) Navigate to Sites > All Sites

3) Click Edit Site > Check if Info- SiteURL is correct and also check if Settings > SitUrl and HomeUrl are correct

**VHosts**

If this is all correct, then you have a problem with your vhosts file. You will need to configure your vhosts file to point the domain name towards the Wordpress installation.

**DNS Records**

If the vhosts files are correct, you will need to check if the DNS records for your domain and subdomain are correct.

Get back to me if you need any help :)